# $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ open and bounded and $\phi \in C_b^{\infty}(\Omega;\mathbb{R})\implies$ $\phi$ has bounded derivative?

Tags: calculus, examples-counterexamples

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be an open and bounded set. Is it possible that a function $\phi \in C_b^{\infty}(\Omega;\mathbb{R})$ *(so $\phi$ is smooth, bounded and defined on a bounded open set)* can have an unbounded derivative? I tried to find some examples but I could never have all the conditions in the same time.

example where the domain is closed, **bounded**, and the function **smooth** : $[-1,1]\to\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto\sqrt{(1-x^2)}$

example where the domain is **open**, **bounded**, function non-smooth : $(-1,1)\to \mathbb{R} : x\mapsto \sqrt{|x|}$

example where the domain is **open**, unbounded, function is **smooth** : $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} : x\mapsto\sin(x^2)$

Comment: $x\mapsto \sqrt{x}$ on $]0,1[$ is smooth and has unbounded first derivative

Comment: $(0,1)\to\mathbb R, x\mapsto\sqrt x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, $x\mapsto \sqrt{1-x^2}$ is not smooth on $[-1,1]$ (at least, not in the sense of a function being smooth on a manifold with boundary) because, since $\lim_{t\to 1^-}\frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}-1}{t}=-\infty$, the function cannot be extended to a differentiable function on any open neighbourhood of $[-1,1]$.

Anyways, you have the answer to the question right there: consider $\phi(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $\Omega=(-1,1)$.